# Change the library that a package links to

Tags: r, r-sf

I am trying to perform some coordinate reference system conversions using a very recently developed coordinate system (Equal Earth). This coordinate system is part of the PROJ 5.2.0 library which I have installed on my system.

However, the R package 'sf' (I have the most recent version installed) continues link to PROJ 4.9.3, which does not contain the new coordinate system, when I use library(sf). Any ideas about how I can get it it link to the newer library?

Comment: This is probably a better question for the developers of the package rather than the general community. Try asking at https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the 5.2.0 version of the PROJ library on your system, and then install sf as a source package. This will be easier is you are running e.g. linux or OSX with homebrew than, say, windows. In case you are running windows and want to use the rwinlib toolchain, you'll need to update the sources in rwinlib and compile that first, see https://github.com/rwinlib/gdal2 .

I hope that we will be able roll out binary CRAN distributions of sf and rgdal linking to GDAL 3.0 and PROJ 6 some time this summer or fall.